# htaccess modify rule to match with or without htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteRule ^section-([^.]+)/([^.]+)-C([^.]+)/?$ /index.php?section=$1&dossier=$2&catid=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^section-([^.]+)/?$ /index.php?section=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)-C([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?section=tshirt&dossier=$1&catid=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

This rule works almost perfectly, except it doesn't match url with index.php at the end. So something like this

```
https://www.domain.com/test-C118036/index.php?p=2&couleur=120
```

will result in 404 error, but this one will work:

```
https://www.domain.com/test-C118036/?p=2&couleur=120
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a rule before these rules to strip `/index.php` from URI:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.+)/index\.php$ /$1 [NC]

RewriteRule ^section-([^.]+)/([^.]+)-C([^.]+)/?$ index.php?section=$1&dossier=$2&catid=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^section-([^.]+)/?$ index.php?section=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)-C([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?section=tshirt&dossier=$1&catid=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: But what if the visitors reach an URL that doesn't have any GET variable after the folder name ? Like https://www.domain.com/test-C118036/

Comment: That will be taken care by your list rule. Have you tried it?